# Why my unit test doesn't cover gui component generation code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, gui-testing

I'm trying to do unit test for the code which generates GUI components.

This is my test code.

```
@Test
public void testMainFrame() {
    mFrame = new MainFrame();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        fail("MainFrame Test Fail");
    }

    assertTrue(true);
}
```

And the target code is here.

```
public MainFrame() {
    super("Title");

    /* Main page */
    clayout = new CardLayout();
    headerPane = new JPanel(clayout);
    statusField = new JTextArea("TEST TEXT!!!");
    statusField.setEditable(false);
    headerPane.add(statusField);
    startButton = new JButton("Start");
    closeButton = new JButton("Close");

    startButton.addActionListener(this);
    closeButton.addActionListener(this);

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setSize(500, 400);

    headerPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));

    mainPane = new JPanel();
    mainPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPane.add(headerPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

As you can see above, the target of the test just generates the GUI components.

What I wonder is, my test just covers the first line, `super("Title");`.

For this reason, my code coverage reduced much.

And I could see this result in sonar report.

Why my test does not cover the left codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an exception, which was not found in eclipse but found in jenkins.

To solve this, xvnc plugin is necessary in jenkins, and vncserver should be installed in server.

Actually, the exception was 'headlessException' and it was only found in jenkins, not eclipse though your test was successful.

so, check the `unit test success > yourTest.java > show details`. If you have an error what I had, you can see the error message here.

reference : [Java HeadlessException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640902/java-headlessexception)
this is my question and answer.